# What CiviCRM permissions do I need to grant in order to allow "create user record" for a CiviCRM contact

Tags: wordpress, contacts, permissions, user

What CiviCRM permissions do I need to grant in order to allow "create user record" for a CiviCRM contact?

I want to allow for a user with a certain role ("Organizer") to create a CMS(wordpress) user for a certain CiviCRM contact -- contacts the user is in a certain relation with. I would like to not only allow editing the contact for that user, but also allow for "create user record"

[image]

Is it possible to grant that permission at this granularity? Or does the "Organizer" have to get Admin privileges?
Is there another way to allow the "Organizer" to effect, that the contact can get a WP account? (e.g. by providing a registration link that is tied to the contacts email adress or something of the like?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In wordpress it's the `create_users` permission:

- https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/79ac44cf780f867e37ed2c11cc7e9855ec6df5e0/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php#L1178
- https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/79ac44cf780f867e37ed2c11cc7e9855ec6df5e0/CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact.php#L3048

And as noted in the comments by @mplh you can use a plugin like [user role editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) to set the permissions granted to roles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and showing a way how to trouble shoot such questions by looking at the code! I have one more practical question for users that may not be able to change the code: Can I grant the "create_users" permission to a specific wordpress role in the "WordPress Access Control" or some other admin panel? If not, how could I go about adding that possibility to the "WordPress Access Control"?

Comment: I found a solution myself: the `create_users` permission is a Wordpress permission. It can be set for a Wordpress Role in Wordpress itself, e.g. by using a plugin like [user-role-editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) @Demerit: maybe you can add this clarification in your answer